# NavigationDrawer is not working?

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

Program is not responding as soon as I run it there is no compile time error.
For more information check the link below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rs4LW3GxOgE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
 ListView mListView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle;
private custome_adapter adp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adp = new custome_adapter(this);
    mListView.setAdapter(adp);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


    toogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"opening the Scroll",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"closing the scroll",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toogle);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}



@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toogle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    toogle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   if(toogle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
   {
       return true;
   }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




}





class custome_adapter extends BaseAdapter


{

private Context context;

 String[] week;

int[] images = {
        R.drawable.a,
        R.drawable.b,
        R.drawable.c,
        R.drawable.d,
        R.drawable.e

};

public custome_adapter(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
   week= context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.week);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return week.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return week[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row =null;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_row, parent, false);

    }
    else{

        row = convertView;
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
    textView.setText(week[position]);

    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: Check All Answer which related to this otherwise take any tutorial from other sites.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a **cool** navigation drawer without sweating , Android Studio has a Template in it,you just need to start the project with a Navigation Drawer , ***to achieve this do the following:***

1.**Click on File**

2.Then New > New Project

3.Then Click **Next** , *Until you reach* **Add an Activity to Mobile**

4. Then **click** next and **Finish** .

Comment: but iam a beginner i want to learn first then i try template later

Comment: yeah it's true , but for industry work were time is limited we tend sometimes to use templates. Even when you create this Template , you van get ,ore ideas to give you an answer because that video was using a ListView and a ListView was replaced by a RecyclerView , so soon you wil revert to this